# how msd reduces examine number of keys

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I am reading MSD at following link.

http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/18RadixSort.pdf

Here it is mentioned that in MSD may not have to examine all the keys on page 20. How is this related to program on page 18. When I try to put the example in code walk through I am not able to understand how we reduced to examine all the keys.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have: (0's can really be anything)

```
600000
100000
300000
500000
400000
200000
```

If you only sort on the most significant digit, you get:

```
100000
200000
300000
400000
500000
600000
```

After this the array is already sorted and we can stop - there's no need to check the other digits.

While it may not be so ideal in practice, there are certainly cases where we don't have to evaluate *all* the digits of *all* the elements.

The `if (hi <= lo + 1) return;` statement should cause it to return if there's only one element in the subarray, preventing checking unnecessary data.